# Backbone's model prototype fetch vs backbone fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I was looking at a website's model code and I had a question regarding the prototype. I understand that is's useful for inheritance in Javascript.

In this example...

```
define([], function () {

    "use strict";

    /**
     * Data Model
     *
     * @type {Backbone.Model}
     */
    var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults : {

        },

        urlRoot : '/api/..../../..',

        fetch : function() {
            Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });

    return Datamodel;
});
```

Why do we need to do `Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);` instead of plain old `Model.fetch();`

**I'm super duper confused. Why even use prototype in order to fetch something? I can't understand the usecase here.**

Please help.

Comment: Please refrain from adding signatures; apart from the fact that they are noise and don't add anything to the question, your posts are signed with your user card.

Comment: will keep in mind thanks @Daedalus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done in order to do some pre-prosessing before invoking the actual fetch method. On in other words, we override the models `fetch` method with our custom logic which eventually invokes the original `fetch` method if needed.

For example:

```
fetch : function(options) {
    if(options.someFlag){
           var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
           // fetch the data from localStorage
           // dfd.resolve(resultingDataFromLocalStorage);
           return dfd.promise();
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This is a better solution than having the code for deciding how the fetch should proceed in all the view's that's invoking `model.fetch()`.

Of course, without custom logic in there, as in your example this is pretty unnecessary.

Comment: Note that the `return` in the `if` branch should return a promise because code might rely on that interface.

Comment: @try-catch-finally can you elaborate? Why would you need to return a promise object? If i have my local variables in place? Kinda confused. a Code would really help!

Comment: @TechnoCorner Imagine some other developer is using your model... he'll assume it's fetch returns a jqxhr like normal models does. So if you override it and return a primitive or something instead, his code will break. See the update in answer.